# Raise an exception if RuntimeWarning found during pytest execution

Tags: python, pytest

I want to raise an error if RuntimeWarning's occurred during pytest call. The problem is, the solutions below are doing nothing - each time I call pytest, RuntimeWarnings are still warnings:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=RuntimeWarning)
```

```
# setup.cfg
filterwarnings =
    error::RuntimeWarning
    default
```

```
pytest -W error::RuntimeWarning
```

Meanwhile, *ignore::RuntimeWarning* (and error::DeprecationWorning)works as expected. What's wrong with my code?
Warning example below:

```
  /app/src/pbp_data_platfrom/tests/test_service.py:20: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AsyncMock.__call__' was never awaited
    assert send_events_mock.called_count == 1
  Enable tracemalloc to get traceback where the object was allocated.
  See https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html#resource-warnings for more info.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
```

P.S. I know I can add the ***error*** option into filterwarning so it will raise an error each time any warning found (and it will work, I've tested it a couple of times). But this solution looks a bit clunky.

Comment: There is a solved GitHub issue with the problem just like yours: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/184#issue-684234787